# Bubble sort on string

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

```
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int i,j,temp;
     char str[]="geeksforgeeks";
     for(i=1;str[i];i++)
     {
         for(j=0;str[j]!='\0';j++)
         {
             if(str[j]>str[j+1])
             {
                 temp=str[j];
                 str[j]=str[j+1];
                 str[j+1]=temp;
             }      
         }
     }
     for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         printf("%c",str[i]);
     }
}
```

I want it to be done without calculating the length of the string.As i know that the bug is in the condition statement of for loop then tell me what it should be?

Comment: Error!! `if(str[j]>str[j+1])` is UB on the last element.

Comment: You should also provide a sample test case (input and output). Or if the code crashes tell us the error message! This  will help give a better idea of what is wrong :)

Comment: It is currently extremely unclear what you're asking, and what you're trying to do. Explain what you're trying to do, what's going wrong, and why you know it's wrong. Then ask a clear question. You'll generate a lot more willingness to help by doing this, because we all want to help, but we don't want to spend forever figuring out what you want.

Comment: i want to sort the string using bubble sort without calculating the length of the string

Comment: .. to refine my previous comment, not exacly UB but comparing with the string terminator.

Comment: @sony I would have thought there are numerous bubble sort examples available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Weather Vane has pointed out already, error is at `str[j]>str[j+1]`. This will switch the second last character with the NULL terminator (and thus cause you to miss your end condition for the for loop).

To fix this change the for loop end condition to `str[j+1]!='\0'` and add a check at the beginning to make sure the first character in the array is not '\0'! I also suggest researching Bubble search because this code has a lot of extra iterations!

Comment: yeah i think its better to define a variable and when there is no swap then after nested loop we should break the loop to reduce iterations